# Move Cart to Header in Magento 1.7

Tags: php, magento

I’m having trouble in moving the mini cart from sidebar to header. I’ve tried all the tutorials available in the internet but it doesn’t work.

I also tried adding this in the header block of layout\page.xml

```
<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" as="topcart" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml"
```

And then in my page\html\header.phtml, I use the code below to call the cart but nothing happened.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topcart'); ?>
```

The solution above works in magento 1.6, but not in version 1.7

Comment: you might get a better answer from the experts at http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to create or update your local.xml file IF you do not have a local.xml file you can create one in

app->frontend->[Package Name]->[Theme Name]->layout->local.xml

Once this is created you can copy exactly what I have in this post into that file for a start of how to use one.

DO ALL UPDATES THROUGH A LOCAL.XML file not through catalog.xml or checkout.xml !! This will make upgrades significantly easier later down the road. Additionally, you will be able to quickly see all changes you have made to your site in one file.

The below example will add it to the header reference name which will be available on all pages as indicated by the tag and will only be available in the header.phtml file. Duplicate base/default/checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml and rebane that file as topcart.phtml and place it into your theme at [Your Package]/[Your Theme]/template/checkout/cart/topcart.phtml by doing this you are cloning the sidebar functionality and adding it to the header. Then you can make any edits through the topcart.phtml file without affecting base functionality.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="topcart_mini" as="topcart" template="checkout/cart/topcart.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Then call it in header.phtml with

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topcart'); ?>
```

This is the proper way to modify Magento,  this makes upgrades quite simple. Additionally, it does not edit any core files.

Answer (score 0):

Insteat of copying block xml, you should reference it like

```
<reference name="block-name">

</reference>
```